# Calculus problem about equality of series and integral

Tags: calculus

I am trying to check the following equality
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+k^2x^2}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+t^2}\, dt.$$

I have started with writing $x=1/n$ but can't figure out the trick to convert the sum into the right-hand integral.

PS I know that

$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+t^2}\, dt=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1/n}{1+(k/n)^2}$$
but I am not sure how to do the above problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You actually want a one-sided limit $x \to 0+$.  Obviously for $x < 0$ the sum is negative.

Answer (score 3):

For $s \ge k x \ge t > 0$ we have $$ \dfrac{1}{1+s^2} \le \dfrac{1}{1+k^2 x^2} \le \dfrac{1}{1+t^2}$$ and therefore if $x > 0$ and $k \ge 1$,
$$\int_{kx}^{(k+1)x} \dfrac{dt}{1+t^2} \le \dfrac{x}{1+k^2 x^2} \le \int_{(k-1)x}^{kx} \dfrac{dt}{1+t^2}$$
Summing from $k=1$ to $\infty$, 
$$\int_{x}^\infty \dfrac{dt}{1+t^2} \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{x}{1+k^2 x^2} \le \int_0^\infty \dfrac{dt}{1+t^2}$$

Now take the limit as $x \to 0+$.

Comment: Very nice answer Prof.